# iText: Setting image interpolation for images on a page

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext, interpolation

I want to iterate through the pages of a PDF and write a new PDF where all images have interpolation set to false. I was expecting to be able to do something like the following, but I cannot find a method of accessing the Images or Rectangles on the PDF page.

```
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(outFileName));
copy.newPage();
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inFileName);
for(int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    PdfImportedPage importedPage = copy.getImportedPage(reader, i);
    for(Image image : importedPage.images())
        image.isInterpolated(false);
    copy.addPage(importedPage);
}
reader.close();
```

There is, however, no PdfImportedPage.images(). Any suggestions on how I might otherwise do the same?

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't be  that easy.  There's no high-level way of doing what you want.  You'll have to enumerate the resources looking for XObject Images, and clear their /Interpolate flag.

And you'll have to do it before creating the PdfImportedPage because there's no public way to access their resources.  Grr.

```
void removeInterpolation( int pageNum ) {
  PdfDictionary page = someReader.getPageN(pageNum);
  PdfDictionary resources = page.getAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);

  enumResources(resources);
}

void enumResource( PdfDictionary resources) {
  PdfDictionary xobjs = resources.getAsDict(PdfName.XOBJECTS);

  Set<PdfName> xobjNames = xobjs.getKeys();
  for (PdfName name : xobjNames) {

    PdfStream xobjStream = xobjs.getAsStream(name);

    if (PdfName.FORM.equals( xobjStream.getAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE))) {
      // xobject forms have their own nested resources.
      PdfDictionary nestedResources = xobjStream.getAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);
      enumResources(nestedResources);
    } else {
      xobjStream.remove(PdfName.INTERPOLATE);
    }
  }
}
```

There's quite a bit of null-checking that's skipped in the above code.  A page doesn't have to have a resource dictionary, though they almost always do.  Ditto for XObject Forms.  All the `getAs*` functions will return null if the given key is missing or of a different type... you get the idea.